# How can I check for a specific day of the week using NSDate in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate

Using NSDate and Swift, I want to make an if statement that triggers on a particular day of the week.

Specifically, when the current day is Monday the text of a label named `labelone` should be "Have a nice week" and when it's any other day `labelone` should be hidden.

I know the code to change the text from the label and make it hidden, but how can I structure an if statement using NSDate in this way?

This is what I've tried:

```
let today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = calendar!.components([.Weekday], fromDate: today)

if components.weekday == 2 {
    print("Hello Monday")
} else {
    print("It's not Monday")
}
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would accomplish the task.

```
var CurrentDate = NSDate()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ccc"

let Monday = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(CurrentDate)
let isMonday = "Mon"
if Monday == isMonday {
   print("It's Monday")
}
else {
   let otherDay = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(CurrentDate)
   print(otherDay)
}
```

Comment: What happens if your device is using another language? Will it still be "Mon" or will it be localised to the current language? 

Comment: @Sebbe The answer below takes that in to account.  As it would use the day of the week but you have to localize your output string then.

Answer (score 17):

Use `Calendar` / `NSCalendar` to perform your calendrical calculations:

### Swift 3 and up

```
let today = Date()
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let components = calendar.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today)

if components.weekday == 2 {
    print("Hello Monday")
} else {
    print("It's not Monday")
}
```

### Swift 2

```
let today = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let components = calendar!.components([.Weekday], fromDate: today)

if components.weekday == 2 {
    print("Hello Monday")
} else {
    print("It's not Monday")
}
```

Monday, Tuesday, etc. are only defined in the Gregorian calendar. Some, like the Chinese lunar calendar has no concept of week day at all.

Comment: 1=Sunday, 2=Monday, ...

Comment: @MartinR thanks. Got mixed up with other languages

Comment: Does your code also work with swift 1?

Comment: What if the first day of the week is Monday and not Sunday?

Comment: @aleciuf I tried setting the locale to Norway – where Monday is the first day of the week – and it didn't seem to matter